# How to make my post blog page full width in Google blogger

Tags: templates, blogger

I tried looking in the web for a solution with Arabic English but nothing helped me make my post blog page full width in Google blogger.
I'm trying to develop a Google blogger theme but I get stuck. In one thing it's my post blog page: it won't display in full screen when I click at any post so I'm turning to you for help. Please help me. Below is my blogger website that I'm using to develop my blogger template. I forget I'm looking for code that I need to post in header to make my post blog page display in full screen.
I remember having had such code but I lost it.

https://mohsubarashi.blogspot.com/

I tried looking in the world wide web.